# React native firebase phone authentication, if code sent navigate to otp screen

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I am using react native firebase, if code sent then i want to navigate to otp screen

But it shows an warning :

```
Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state. Check:

OtpVerification > params.confirm._auth._app._deleteApp (Function)

This can break usage such as persisting and restoring state. This might happen if you passed non-serializable values such as function, class instances etc. in params. If you need to use components with callbacks in your options, you can use 'navigation.setOptions'
```

My code :

In login Screen :

```
async function signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
try {
  const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

  props.navigation.navigate('OtpVerification', {
    confirm: confirmation,
    phoneNo,
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

}

In Otp Screen :

```
async function confirmCode() {
if (otp) {
  try {
    await confirm.confirm(otp);
    props.navigation.navigate('OnBoarding');
  } catch (error) {
    AlertMsg('Invalid OTP');
  }
} else {
  AlertMsg('Please Enter OTP');
}
```

}

Comment: This can happen if you are passing non-serializable values such as class instances, functions etc. in params. React Navigation warns you in this case because this can break other functionality such state persistence, deep linking etc.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe in belive function where you have `confirmation` variable, You might have to pass some constant value over there handling the return of firebase signin.

```
async function signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
try {
  const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

  props.navigation.navigate('OtpVerification', {
    confirm: confirmation,
    phoneNo,
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Check this document - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/#i-get-the-warning-non-serializable-values-were-found-in-the-navigation-state

This expo for your navigation - https://snack.expo.dev/vKpugczaG